# How to make Separable Pagination in Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5, pagination

I need to separate the pagination. My values are coming so messy. First of all look at the table.
My view should be like this.

|---2015-----2016-----2017-----2018-|

|-----X----------X---------X----------X----|

|-----X----------X---------X----------X----|

<- Previous --1--2--3--...--10--11-- Next->

When i click random year, all values are coming, but just up to ten images can be displayed, then another ten must be load with paginate buttons.

But there is a problem, all datas are coming from 2015-2016. If i change the query with created_at, desc or smt all datas are coming from just 2018.

I need to balanced solution, is there a way for get 10 data for all year?

Comment: You should probably provide some code for this... It's a little vague without it unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea sir? Any opinion is good for me. I am stuck. Not codes. Opinions, ideas etc...

Comment: My idea/opinion is that you need to add your code to the question. We won't be able to help without it.

Comment: But i can't for now. Paginate(number)  is existing query in laravel. Its doing all job. My question is about customizing a pagination query. As i said. I just need a hint.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I understand your question quite right, but it sounds to me like you're trying to present 10 entries at a time for *each* year displayed.  You don't need to customize how pagination works.  But you do need to tinker with your data to make it fit the existing behavior.

You may not need to do all of the the following.  But to cover all bases- to assume that you want an EloquentCollection of Models that are capable of calling the `links()` method on within your View, here's how to manually build a composite-result-object

1. Query each year independently.  Paginate all of them.
2. Identify the largest result-set, to know what value to present for a "last page" link
3. Merge them into a single Collection by way of the `merge()` method
4. Create an instance of LengthAwarePaginator.  Send to is your merged results, the value of the highest total identified in #2, the number per page derived from your GET variable, and the current page number.  By default, the current page number will be defined as the GET variable `page`.
5. Send that LengthAwarePaginator object to your View.  Let it break out the results by year, and present the pagination `links()` as normal.

Comment: By the way, I'd advise against querying on `created_at` or `updated_at` fields.  Those are largely just meant to reflect when the DB entry was created, for debugging/historical reasons.  You can get into some trouble if you assume that the date an entry was created *necessarily* reflects something about what that data is suppose to represent.